# Formal derivation of the chain rule for partial derivatives

Tags: analysis

I want to derive the chain rule for partial derivatives, that is if $\gamma (t) = (x(t),y(t))$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial  f\circ \gamma}{\partial  t} (t) = \frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x} (x(t),y(t)) \frac{\partial  x}{\partial  t} (t) + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial  y} (x(t),y(t)) \frac{\partial  y}{\partial  t} (t).
\end{align*}
Here is what I have so far:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  t} (t)(h) &  = Df (\gamma (t))(h) \\ 
 &  = Df (\gamma (t)) (D\gamma (t)(h)) \\
 &  = Df (\gamma (t))( D\gamma (t)(h_1\mathbf{e}_{1} ) + D\gamma (t)(h_2\mathbf{e}_{2} )) \\
 &  = Df (\gamma (t))\left(h_1 \begin{pmatrix} x' (t) \\ 
  0  \end{pmatrix} +  h_2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 
  y' (t) \end{pmatrix}\right) \\
 &  = h_1 D_1f (\gamma (t)) x' +  h_2 D_2 f(\gamma (t))y'.
\end{align*}
Now I need to look at what $D_if(\gamma (t))$ looks like. We have
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x_1} (\gamma (t))\right) = D_1 f(\gamma (t)) = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(\gamma (t) + r\mathbf{e}_{1} ) - f(\gamma (t))}{r} & = \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{f(x(t) + r,y(t)) - f(x(t),y(t))}{r}
\end{align*}
Now I need show that this is $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x}(\gamma (t)) $ but I don't know how to formulate it as $x$ here is a variable and we have only defined partial derivatives in terms of coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example, $x_1$ means with respect to the first coordinate as written above. Maybe what I have above is the definition of $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x} $?. Maybe we can count this $r$, per the above, as variation on $x(t)$ so it os okay?  I am not sure. Could someone clarify this for me? Specifically, what is meant by $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x} $ where $x$ is variable rather than a direction?

Comment: $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  x}$ and $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  y},$ in the RHS of the identity you want to prove, are usual but uncomfortable notations for "partial derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. its first and second variables". The letters $x,y$ here are (usual but) completely arbitrary. You could as well denote them by $\partial_1f$ and $\partial_2f.$ And they are equal to what you wrote, i.e. to the directional derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. the first and second vectors of the canonical basis. Your proof is fine.

Comment: Just one remark: in the identity you want to prove, the LHS should not be written $\frac{\partial  f}{\partial  t} (t) $ but  $\frac{d f\circ\gamma}{d t} (t) ,$ or $(f\circ\gamma)'(t).$

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I think I understand now. What confused me was the notation.